# Is it possbile to import a file once and use it everywhere without importing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've to write few methods that will be used throughout my React Applications.

One way is to create a utility file and put all methods inside the file. And wherever the methods needed import the file and call the methods.
In this way I've to import it everywhere.

Another way is to bind the methods in `window` object. Which I don't think is a good way.

I was searching for some webpack plugins. But haven't found anything useful. It would be great if someone can point me in right direction. All I want is to just import a file full of method once, and use these methods anywhere without the need to importing the file again and again.

Comment: tbh,you have to mention what you mean by everywhere. if here the everywhere is in the same code the answer is yes and if its in another code then **NO!**

Comment: Can you tell me why you don't want to import it everywhere you need it ?

Comment: @HichamELBSI for the sake of clarity. Like if I have one constant which is used in 50file. Then I've to import it 50times. 
In iOS development, we can do this by using `.pch` files, I was wondering if we can do the same in web app as well.

Comment: are you searching for the ProvidePlugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: Yes Abrar everywhere is in same code, within same applications.